# Slideshow next image div to be cut in 40-50%

Tags: javascript, css, slideshow

I want to have a slideshow with next image div that is to be cut in 40-50%.

It means that the next image to be shown has to be cut 40-50% so that it looks like a slideshow.

```css
.slideshow_image_div {
  height: 300px;
  border: thin black solid;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slideshow_image_div .slideshow_images {
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.slideshow_images img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow_image_div b">
  <div class="slideshow_images">
    <img src="http://cl.jroo.me/z3/q/R/R/d/a.aaa-Unique-Nature-Beautiful-smal.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="slideshow_images">
    <img src="http://cl.jroo.me/z3/q/R/R/d/a.aaa-Unique-Nature-Beautiful-smal.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="slideshow_images">
    <img src="http://cl.jroo.me/z3/q/R/R/d/a.aaa-Unique-Nature-Beautiful-smal.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the whole slide to appear in the same line, you can give `white-space: nowrap` and removed `float` along with giving a `display: inline-block` and removed the hard-coded height, so that it really looks like a slide container:

```css
.slideshow_image_div {
  border: thin black solid;
  padding: 5px 0 0 5px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.slideshow_image_div .slideshow_images {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.slideshow_images img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow_image_div b">
  <div class="slideshow_images">
    <img src="http://cl.jroo.me/z3/q/R/R/d/a.aaa-Unique-Nature-Beautiful-smal.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="slideshow_images">
    <img src="http://cl.jroo.me/z3/q/R/R/d/a.aaa-Unique-Nature-Beautiful-smal.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="slideshow_images">
    <img src="http://cl.jroo.me/z3/q/R/R/d/a.aaa-Unique-Nature-Beautiful-smal.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```